# How can I use SSL3 to talk to a server?

Tags: mac-osx, openssl

I am trying to get a wireshark trace that I can decrypt for a request between a client and an ALB. In order to decrypt the transaction, I need to force the client/server to disable PFC (perfect forward secrecy). I have access to the server private key.

When I do this:

```
openssl s_client -connect server:443 -debug -msg -state -cipher AES128-SHA
```

it works.

However when I do this:

```
openssl s_client -connect keystone-ext.develop.zillow.net:443 -debug -msg -state -cipher AES128-SHA -ssl3
```

it fails. The output is as follows:

```
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure SSL_connect:failed in SSLv3
read server hello A 31996:error:14094410:SSL
routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL
alert number 40 31996:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl
handshake
failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:566:
```

I am using:

```
$ openssl version OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to talk to a server with SSLv3. The server doesn't support SSLv3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use SSL3 to talk to a server?

Don't. Do not change the protocol (or use OpenSSL that old), that alters the security. Perfect forward secrecy is a feature.

Instead, use [session key logging on a client, or server](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/). Set environment variable `SSLKEYLOGFILE` to a file for the trace. This is supported by a few clients, notably browsers, NSS, and [libcurl](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/01/15/inspect-curls-tls-traffic/). Then [point Wireshark at it](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret):  Edit > Preferences, Protocols > SSL > (Pre)-Master-Secret log filename.

Edit: another reference for TLS decryption is [SSL/TLS decrption presentation from SharkFest ASIA 2018](https://sharkfestasia.wireshark.org/assets/presentations18/19.pdf). It calls out that ECDHE cannot be decrypted with just the RSA private key. With a reminder that TLS 1.3 will be all PFS.  It also describes the state of more implementations of SSL key logging, notably OpenSSL and deriviaves let applications call `SSLCTXsetkeylogcallback()` while NSS and GnuTLS have the `SSLKEYLOGFILE` environment variable.

So, for statically linked OpenSSL, you can have the developer use a different TLS library, or implement their own callback function with logging, or you [dig out the debugger to extract it yourself](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80158/extract-pre-master-keys-from-an-openssl-application). Note that switching out the libssl in use (and updating it) is easier if dynamically linked.

Alternatives include terminating the TLS earlier like on a proxy and capturing unencrypted packets, or removing PFS and decrypting with the private key.

Comment: Thank you! I did that for clients that support it. But I have one client (phantomjs) that statically links openssl. Is there a way to change the cipher for openssl using an environment variable?

Comment: Do not change the cipher. Extract the pre master keys on the server side, or with OpenSSL's callback. See edit.

Answer (score 5):

The server you are likely trying to communicate to does not do SSL v3. Any decently configured server in 2019 does not talk SSL v3, and SSL/TLS requires a compatible cipher set at both ends in order to communicate with the given cipher.

The reason older ciphers like this are disabled is precisely to stop nefarious actors from doing what you're trying to do.

You'll need to find some other way of dumping your payload I'm afraid.

Comment: But... when I use TLSv1 I can see that it is using that same cipher I am providing. Also, I can get SSLv3 to work when I dont provide a cipher... I have edited my question.